Can wire nuts be outside a bath fan's junction box?
Had a really old bathroom fan removed and installed a new Panasonic one.  When wiring it, we were not able to put the wire nuts in the fan's junction box because the wire was just not long enough (we tried pulling just a little bit but it's the most we can do).
So my first question is : is it safe to put the wires back as shown in the picture?  And if not, what would be my best course of action to make this safe?  Please note that I'm in a condo, so no attic access.



Also, in most jurisdictions, since you are in an apartment building with other owners you need to get a licensed electrician to do the work otherwise you will be liable for any issues (fires) and your insurance will not cover you.

Cables can only have their sheaths removed inside junction boxes. A fan or similar equipment will often have an integral junction box for making connections. This must be fixed.
It appears that there is a few inches of cable sheath visible towards the right side in picture one. Assuming that is indeed the case:

Install a metal box above the fan. Ideal would be to mount it to the wood that is on the right side. But I have a feeling you can't do that without it blocking physical installation of the fan. In which case it may just have to be loose so that when you push up the fan it gets pushed up and out of the way. USE A METAL BOX. One knockout with clamp for the existing cable, one for a new cable.
Add a short cable (probably between one and two feet) between the new box and the fan. 14/2 if a 15A circuit, 12/2 if a 20A circuit. Clamp it in the new box, strip a few inches of the cable sheath inside the box, ground to the box directly, wire nut black and white to the old black and white.
The other end of the new cable should be wire-nutted to the fan wires INSIDE THE FAN BOX. That fan box is itself a junction box. There should be a clamp on circular hole for the new cable going in (which currently has the fan's wires coming out) to keep the cable secure and to keep the box properly protected from bugs crawling in, etc. If you can't find the clamp, measure the hole and get a new clamp from a hardware store - I'm sure it is a standard size.

You don't want the new cable way too long, but a little longer than absolutely necessary will make the installation easier.
While a junction box inside the ceiling is normally not allowed, it is normal to have a junction in the ceiling above equipment (lights, fans, etc.) where the junction box is 100% accessible as soon as you remove the equipment.
However, checking a little further, it looks like probably some combination of (a) my memory not 100% as to what is/isn't permitted and/or (b) a lot of stuff out there that isn't 100% code-compliant. The normal rule for junction boxes is "accessible without tools". An exception is made for junction boxes attached to a device - but that is not the case here, or rather it is with the original fan fixture but not with my solution. There is an allowance for boxes way up above a drop-ceiling with cables down to fixtures installed in the ceiling, but that is not the case here either. Or for a junction box behind an appliance - e.g., in the back of a cabinet where tools are needed to remove the appliance but the box is permanently installed in the cabinet to service the appliance. That last case is close to this, except in that case the box is not simply sitting in the ceiling but is inside the cabinet that holds the appliance, which is a little different.
The end result is that my solution is a lot better than the existing situation, but the junction box accessibility could still be a real code issue.
A slight variation from a comment from Huesmann, which should be 100% code-compliant, is to find a ceiling location that the existing cable with sheath can reach and put a box there with a plain cover plate. Run the new cable from there to the fan. That results in an extra blank plate on the ceiling, but if the plate is painted (or naturally if white plate and white ceiling) to match the ceiling it won't be very noticeable.
One other solution is to install a very large box such that it can reach from the existing cable sheath on one end all the way over to where the fan wires exit the fan's integral box on the other end, and screw everything together. That should be 100% compliant, but would like be a real pain to install.
Also, as noted in another comment, condo, so no attic access is a real concern as well. In most jurisdictions work in a multi-tenant building must be done by licensed electricians.

I thought junction boxes could not be hidden in walls or ceiling.  Is  the fact that what you suggest is accessible if the fan is removed , approved by code?

@RMDman I am pretty sure this is no different than a junction box above a ceiling light fixture.

Thank you very much for your answer!  I'll get this fixed ASAP, but in the meantime, can I live with this for a week or two?

But an electrical box above a ceiling light fixture is accessible from the ceiling. The light fixture just acts as a cover to the electrical box. That fan assembly once installed would basically conceal any electrical box shoved up or mounted up within the ceiling once it is screwed into place and the drywall replaced.

Have the ROMEX Cable Splice Kits that were made Tyco / TE Connectivity been taken off the market? These used to be available at both Home Depot and Lowes for about $15 but are now not sold at either outfit. They were supposedly approved for in wall / in ceiling cable splicing. https://www.lowes.com/pd/TE-Connectivity-20-Amp-Volt-White-2-Wire-Connector/50205339

https://www.te.com/en/product-A22899-000.html  The manufacturer is out of stock, but still lists the part as "active"  perhaps demand has outstripped supply?

@MichaelKaras is a fan that much different from a ceiling light in terms of "accessibility?"

@MichaelKaras I found this re: the splices: https://www.reddit.com/r/askanelectrician/comments/10wfv3w/why_have_nm_splice_kits_junction_box_free_been/

Anyway, if the OP is OK with a blanking plate on the ceiling, and if the cable can be accessed, a J-box can be installed in the ceiling at a location that provides sufficient slack in the cable, then a new cable can be routed from the J-box to the fan, and nutted inside the fan's "box."  Put up a dummy fan grille to cover the J-box, if you must.

Install a small junction box flush with the ceiling somewhere along the route of the existing cable, and pull the cable into it. Splice another length of cable long enough to easily reach the fan to it in the box, and wire up the fan. Neither wires nor cables are allowed to enter holes in metal boxes or equipment without a suitable clamp/grommet, as your photo shows. There are cheap little plastic cable clamps that just snap into the holes, available everywhere.

What you have is not safe and not to code.
You already have holes in the ceiling. Look into the holes and see if there is a staple holding the cable to the fan.  If you can, remove the staple and see if that gives you more cable to work with. If not, you need to move the fan closer to the cable end and the connections must be in the junction box and have an strain relief and insulator in the hole.
You will need to have the ceiling repaired anyway. Move the fan so the electric connections are safe.
